# Windows phone 8 how to navigate to an instance of page, loaded with new UserControls?

Tags: windows-phone-8, user-controls, custom-controls

I am new to window phone application and trying to find out how to implement the following scenario:

I have a BasePage that contains two borders which I am going to load different views into.

I would like to maintain the same UI throughout the application by reuse that BasePage. I understand that it is possible to create an instance of the BasePage and populate views. I just don't know how to navigate to this new instance.

```
BasePage Page1 = new BasePage();
Page1.TopSection.Child = new View1();
Page1.BottomSection.Child = new View2();

//How do I Navigate to  Page1?
--------------------------
|      Top Section       |
|      (load view 1)     |
|                        |
|                        |
--------------------------
|     Bottom Section     |
|      (load view 2)     |
|                        |
--------------------------
|          [ Next Page ] |
-------------------------- 
          BasePage Page2 = new BasePage();
          Page2.TopSection.Child = new View3();
          Page2.BottomSection.Child = new View4();

          //How do I Navigate to  Page2?
          --------------------------
          |      Top Section       |
          |      (load view 3)     |
          |                        |
          |                        |
          --------------------------
          |     Bottom Section     |
          |      (load view 4)     |
          |                        |
          --------------------------
          |          [ Next Page ] |
          --------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to `Uri` not to a `Page` instance. You can try to accomplish this requirement in another way. Navigate to `BasePage` `Uri` and pass query string parameter to indicate how the `BasePage` should be customized. Then in the `BasePage` do the customization according to query string parameter received :

```
//for example, to navigate to Page2 :
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/BasePage.xaml?page=page2", UriKind.Relative));

//on Loaded event :
public BasePage_Loaded()
{
    SetupView();
}

public void SetupView()
{
    string page;
    if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("page", out page))
    {  
        switch (page)
        {
            case "page1" :
                ....... 
                break;
            case "page2" :
                this.TopSection.Child = new View3();
                this.BottomSection.Child = new View4();
                break;
            ....... 
        }
    }
}
```